# jQuery DataTable fnDestroy reformats table

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatable, styles

The page loads with the following relevant HTML

```
<table id="tblBlacklist"></table>
```

When the loading is complete, the following JS function is called

```
function getResults() {
 $.ajax({

    type: "POST",
    url: "Blacklist.aspx/GetBlacklist",
    data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg) {

        var $table = $("#tblBlacklist");
        $table.html(msg.d);

        $('#tblBlacklist').dataTable({
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "iDisplayLength": 25
        });

    }
 });
}
```

The user can select a different filter from a select object on the page, which then executes:

```
$('#tblBlacklist').dataTable().fnDestroy()
ViewBlacklistItems();
```

And after the table is populated with new results, it's formatting is completeley different!  How do I get it to keep the same format in the "before" image?

The HTML table being passed back through jQuery (for initial call and sub-calls) contains no CSS...

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up finding this post

[Datatables on-the-fly resizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8278981/datatables-on-the-fly-resizing)

which provides a link to the solution, setting bAutoWidth to false

http://datatables.net/ref#bAutoWidth

My issue was slightly different in that I was not resizing the parent DIV... but was destroying and reconstructing the DataTable with new results.

Comment: *Where* did you set bAutoWidth to false? What does `ViewBlacklistItems()` do? This is not helpful.

Comment: @2rs2ts It's a DataTable parameter, just like bJQueryUI from my OP.