# Datatables with column resizing plugin not resizing correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables

When I resize the header, the body also resizes a bit, but incorrectly. For example:

[image: Example]

The grid is initialized as below:

```
var oTable = $('#grid').dataTable( {
    dom: 'Rlfrtip',
    "scrollX": true,
    "bPaginate": false,
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "bFilter": true,
    "bSort": true,
    "bInfo": false,
    "bAutoWidth": false
  });
```

I'm using the ColReorderWithResize.js v.1.0.7

Any ideas?

Comment: see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8278981/datatables-on-the-fly-resizing

Comment: that does not appear to be related; you can note the parameter suggested there is already set to false.

Comment: does autoWidth:false work?

Answer (score 0):

try to give fixed width like this:

```
  aoColumns: [ 
    { "sWidth": "50px" },
    { "sWidth": "150px" },
    { "sWidth": "50px" },
    { "sWidth": "50px" },
    { "sWidth": "50px" }
  ]
```